# Why CSS variables are not supporting images in safari?

Tags: css, css-variables

I have used CSS variables for image URL. This is working fine in Chrome and Firefox, but not in Safari.

Safari is not showing the image. However other variables with colour values are working fine in Safari.

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

```
:root {
    --download-icon: url('../img/download.png');
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
    :root {
        --download-icon: url('../img/download_white.png');
    }
}

.document-link {
    background: var(--download-icon) no-repeat center;
}
```

Comment: what is the version of your Safari? Depending on the version certain attributes (like var) are not supported, see caniuse.com for more info

Comment: I am using Safari Version 14.0.3 (16610.4.3.1.4). As I mentioned color values in variables are working fine, so var is definitely supported